# How does Lucio's wallride work?

Tags: overwatch

How does Lucio's wallride work? I'm specifically looking for explanation on how speed mechanics work, on how the speed bonus from wallriding stacks and to what actions will I lose speed?  I've tried chaining a few wallrides and they seem to definitely increase the speed boost but if I miss and end up having to do a few hops in between it seems random whether or not I'll go back to the normal speed or still retain most of my speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to [the wiki page](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_Ride) for him and his wall ride you will find the following information:

> Lúcio is able to ride along a wall's face until either the wall ends
>   or he jumps off. He also is able to move vertically at an angle as
>   this happens. After initiating the Wall Ride, as long as the jump
>   button is held, Lúcio will remain wall riding. The only things that
>   will affect the trajectory are adjusting Crossfade and releasing the
>   jump button. While riding the wall, his movement speed is increased by
>   20%.
>
> After releasing from a wall, Lúcio gains a slight burst of speed. He
>   can immediately wall ride into another wall, but he cannot continue to
>   wall ride any wall facing the same direction with the old one,
>   including the original. Lúcio must land on the ground or Wall Ride on
>   a wall facing a different direction to reset this. Curved surfaces is
>   considered changing its direction gradually; it means that Lúcio can
>   indefinitely ride "walls" like Ilios' well and Lijiang Tower's control
>   center wall.

So you are seeing that boost of speed when chaining because of the boost on leaving a wall, and the already 20% boost from being on a wall. You will lose speed if the wall angle is off or you try to go backwards, or miss part of the wall (slip).

In Game Options there is a button to turn on backwards wall riding though. (Holding back and jump).

Comment: Won't include in the answer as it is not confirmed - I believe the bursts do not stack, hopping along the same wall won't exponentially increase your speed.

Comment: In most circumstances, you can't hop along the same wall at all -- see the second sentence in the second paragraph you quoted. Curved walls are a special case, and may be worth some investigation.

Comment: I know, as I said, hopping along the same wall won't increase your speed. - I guess I mean to say hoping from wall to wall won't increase it.